# Set distance between two dynamic Label

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to fix a constant vertical distance between 2 `UILabel`s.
When the first `UILabel` resizes, the `UILabel` below should dynamically adjust it's `Y` position.

This is what I have right now:

```
CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
NSString *labelText = @"Floodgates. Floodgates. Keep 'em intact, gotta get home, gotta... gotta find... anywhere... mrph... just a few more blocks and I'll be there, and then this won't matter anymore... why didn't I just go before I left? I'm such an idiot. There's the hot dog vendor... past him, the bank... then another two blocks and I'll see apartments...";
[myLabel setText:labelText];
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
[myLabel sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];

CGRect labelsrame = CGRectMake(60, 200, 200, 200);
UILabel *myLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelsrame];
[myLabel2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
NSString *label2Text = @"Floodgates. Floodgates. Keep 'em intact, gotta get home, gotta... gotta find... anywhere... mrph... just a few more blocks and I'll be there, and then this won't matter anymore... why didn't I just go before I left? I'm such an idiot. There's the hot dog vendor... past him, the bank... then another two blocks and I'll see apartments... almost home free, keep jogging, brisk... pace... hrm...";
[myLabel2 setText:label2Text];
[myLabel2 setNumberOfLines:0];
[myLabel2 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
[myLabel2 sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel2];
```

Thanks

Comment: These are dynamic Label ?????

Comment: if not then can u suggest me how to creat this type task?

Comment: In short i want to fix distance between these lable. by removing some text in first label it's hight automatically reduced and  distance from second label will change. so i want to fix this distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[myLabel sizeToFit]` (*in your case*) changes the height parameter of `myLabel` while `myLabel2` still starts at y=200 when it should start (*as per your requirement*) immediately after `myLabel`.
Hence, you need to make your frame settings dynamic too.

To fix the `Y` position issues for `myLabel2`, the following should be sufficient:

```
//...
CGRect labelsrame = CGRectMake(60, myLabel.frame.origin.y + myLabel.frame.size.height, 200, 200);
UILabel *myLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelsrame];
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create dynamic frame for both the label like bellow

```
UILabel *lblText1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19, 250, 283, 20)];
lblText1.text = @"What ever your dynamic text";

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280,9999); // label with fix width 280

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [lblText1.text sizeWithFont:lblText1.font
                                       constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                           lineBreakMode:lblText1.lineBreakMode];

CGRect newFrame = lblText1.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
lblText1.frame = newFrame;

// label 2

UILabel *lblText2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19, 280, 283, 20)];
lblText2.text = @"What ever your dynamic text label 2";

CGSize maximumLabelSize1 = CGSizeMake(280,9999); // label with fix width 280

CGSize expectedLabelSize1 = [lblText2.text sizeWithFont:lblText2.font
                                       constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize1
                                           lineBreakMode:lblText2.lineBreakMode];

CGRect newFrame1 = lblText2.frame;
newFrame1.size.height = expectedLabelSize1.height;

newFrame1.origin.y = lblText1.frame.origin.y + lblText1.frame.size.height + 10; // 10 for fix space between 2 label
lblText2.frame = newFrame1;
```